# Evaluating Abs'[2 x] gives different results than evaluating D[Abs[2 x], x]

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I noticed the following difference

```
Assuming[x ∈ Reals, FullSimplify[D[Abs[2 x], x]]]

(* 2 Sign[x] *)

Assuming[x ∈ Reals, FullSimplify[Abs'[2 x]]]

(* Sign[x] *)
```

While it is clear that the first line of code above returns the correct result, I wonder why the call of `Derivative` fails? A little further investigation shows that

```
f[x_] := Abs[2 x] 
f'

(* 2 Derivative[1][Abs][#1] & *)
```

which is correct and implies that the difference might come from with or without `SetDelayed`. But I still do not fully understand why the second code failed.

Comment: I believe Mathematica is treating`Abs'[2x]` as `Abs'[u]` which when simplification  occurs Sign[u]=Sign[2x]->Sign[x]. This can be seen if you substitute x^3 for 2x

Comment: @ubpdqn You are right, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is easier to see what is going on if we look at a function that doesn't need any assumptions about its domain.

```
D[Sin[2 x], x]
```

> ```
> 2 Cos[2 x]
> ```

Now let's look at what is almost the full form of `Sin'[2 x]`

```
Derivative[1][Sin][2 x]
```

> ```
> Cos[2 x]
> ```

That happens because this 2nd form is equivalent to `(Derivative[1][Sin])[2 x]`

Comment: Thanks. According to my understanding, `Derivative` carries out only parts of the entire chain rule; whereas `D` actually calls `Derivative` multiple times to carry out the entire chain rule. This is the relation between `D` and `Derivative`. Please correct me if I am wrong.